# Generate semantic URL with asp.net mvc4 ActionLink in Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I have a below setup in the controller for Public facing web page

`Company -> About -> Partners` ( which i want to be accessed as **Company/About/Partners** )
Action Method

```
public about(string category)
{
  ViewBag.Category = category;
  return View();
}
```

Generation of the link is done as below which is giving me the wrong URL

```
@Html.ActionLink("Partners & Investors", "About", "Company",new { Category = "Partners" },null)
```

**Wrong Url**

`Company/About?Category=Partners%20and%20Investors`

So the question is how does one generate the correct url that i wanted. What should i do ?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Hi andrew i want a url `Company/About/category` but it generates `Company/About?category=value` Can you give some inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Urls will be generated `automatically` when you create new `route` and put it on correct position.

**Add**

Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Category",
    "Company/About/{category}",
    new { controller = "Company", action = "About", category = "default" }
);

// default
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also look at this link: [Advanced Routing](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Routing.html)

Comment: wow it worked. I think routes need to be defined in the route maps before using them. Thanks